# Can I increase the performance of my query by using Where() before OrderBy() in EF Core and SQL Server?

Tags: c#, sql-server, performance, entity-framework, query-optimization

I'm using Entity Framework Core with MS SQL Server and I have the following query on my dbContext:

```cs
var list = await dbContext.MyTable
                          .OrderByDescending(x => x.Timestamp)
                          .Where(x => x.Something == someVar && x.Succeeded)
                          .ToListAsync()
                          .ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Would it make any difference regarding the performance if I move the `OrderByDescending()` from before to after the `Where()`?

Like this:

```cs
var list = await dbContext.MyTable
                          .Where(x => x.Something == someVar && x.Succeeded)
                          .OrderByDescending(x => x.Timestamp)
                          .ToListAsync()
                          .ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Comment: you have the code, you have the data. have you tried _benchmarking it yourself_ to see if there's any difference....? that being said: my guess would be that EF is smart enough to optimise it anyway and produces the same SQL code. you could also check _that_ with the debugger.

Comment: Why not [race your horses](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)?

Comment: I'm not even sure EF would be able to generate a plan that the RDBMS would apply the `ORDER BY` before the `WHERE` @FranzGleichmann . In T-SQL the `WHERE` is [logically processed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#logical-processing-order-of-the-select-statement) *before* the `ORDER BY`. You *might* be able to force it with some "funky" logic with a subquery, but then it would require a `TOP` or `OFFSET` which the code above doesn't include. I too, suspect that these will produce the same SQL.

Comment: Why didn't you just look at the generated SQL before asking a question?

Comment: For SQL performance help, you will need to show us the two generated SQL queries, along with sharing the execution plans via https://brentozar.com/pastetheplan. Please also add the table and index definitions. I would imagine it's highly unlikely to make a difference without a `Take/Skip` or some kind of join.

Comment: There'll be no difference because generated SQL keywords have to be in correct order - WHERE -> ORDER BY. Also, your tests using InMemoryDatabase have no sense because it's not a SQL server engine. Also at the end MSSQL server have it's own powerfull optimization engine - so very often different query === same execution plan.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested I've done some benchmarking. I used a new InMemoryDatabase for every run and filled it with 1 million entries, each with a different timestamp. I run both queries 5 times to get a better baseline for comparison.

Results when `OrderBy()` is put before the `Where()`:

```
1651ms
1096ms
1172ms
1214ms
1391ms
```

Results when `OrderBy()` is put after the `Where()`:

```
735ms
1026ms
894ms
1110ms
939ms
```

Seems like the order of the statements does have an impact, although it's quite small.

Comment: You ask a question about the difference in SQL Server. Then why not test with SQL Server? You won't see any difference.